# Changing NULL to empty

Tags: data-loader, administration, data, migration, data-migration

Migrating from a SQL based system and using dataloader.io.  The NULL values appear to have come over as "NULL" and when I try to create a duplicate rule it is saying there are too many matches.

I tried to use dataloader.io to replace the null values with blanks but the changes won't take (maybe because I'm taking away data?)

Is there a way (other than the 200 at a time updater in the app) for me to globally replace NULL with blank?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was as simple as checking "Insert Nulls" in dataloader.io.  It would have worked in the desktop version of dataloader too.  Basically you need to enable this to allow for the insertion of blanks.